# Debug.DrawLine doesn't go straight

Tags: unity, raycasting

Heres the code:

```
void Update() {
    Debug.DrawLine(attackSpot.position, attackSpot.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * distance), Color.red);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position,  transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * distance), Color.green);
}
```

I'm drawing 2 lines, one is coming from attackSpot and one is coming from own transform.

Reason of this because my Raycast doesn't worked properly, so I decided to see visually to check.

Of course, attackSpot is pointing front direction.

[image]

Rotation of attackSpot in screenshot is local rotation. But when the play game, line coming from attackSpot doesn't go straight, it moves lower direction.

[image]

I also tried

```
Debug.DrawLine(attackSpot.position, attackSpot.forward * distance, Color.red);
```

But has same result. Why my ray doesn't go straight? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Debug.DrawLine(Vector3 inWorldSpace, Vector3 inWorldSpace2, Color color)`

`Debug.DrawLine(attackSpot.position, attackSpot.forward * distance, Color.red);`

Let's set `attackSpot.position` to be `new Vector3(0f, 5f, 0f)` for this example. And leave rotation at `0`s.

Then in your case you would have result - `Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(0f, 5f, 0f), new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f) * distance(4f), Color.red)`.

Thus your drawing positions would be from `new Vector3(0f, 5f, 0f)` to `new Vector3(0f, 0f, 4f)`.

You need to do this :

```
Debug.DrawLine(attackSpot.position, attackSpot.position + attackSpot.forward * distance, Color.red);
```